# End of array in C language

Tags: c, arrays

We know that for character arrays we have the '\0' to identify its end, what about other types of arrays?

I presume it's not a special character such as the '\0' since to declare an integer array of n elements for example you just allocate n * sizeof(int), yet for a character array we account for the '\0'.

Comment: You need to know the array length in advance. The `\0` character  (also called NULL terminator, since the ASCII value of `\0` is 0) is there just for print functions to know when to stop printing the string.

Comment: There's nothing unless you use a special sentinel value of your own for your particular array type.

Comment: You may use a sentinel value if it can't ocurr in the array, otherwise the `'\0'` is what makes the difference between an array and a string.

Comment: The fact that C strings are defined using char arrays and the fact that C arrays are not objects and do not contain their length as a field, required the definition of a terminator character

Comment: @SomethingSomething Depends on how you define object. In the C standard, even regular variables are refered to as objects.

Comment: @Broman , if so, then let's refer to them as cars and if someone argues, we'll say that it depends on how you define a car

Comment: @SomethingSomething Strange answer. Since we are talking about C, I'd say that the C standard is pretty relevant.

Comment: @Broman, I was joking of course. As far as I know, "regular" variables, like int, char and so on are referred to as "primitive types", while structs or class instances are referred to as objects

Comment: @SomethingSomething Didn't get the joke. :)   But you are wrong unfortunately. In the C standard, just about everything is referred to as an object. Look at 6.2.5

Comment: @Broman, ok, I totally accept what you're saying and am thanking you for extending my knowledge. Yet I want to tell my joke again :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C arrays don't have an end marker.

It is your responsibility as the programmer to keep track of the allocated size of the array to make sure you don't try to access element outside the allocated size.

If you do access an element outside the allocated size, the result is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

A character array is just an array of type `char[]`. It has nothing that identifies it's end. What you are talking about is a *c-string*, which is a null-terminated char array. Or to be more correct, a null-terminated contiguous sequence of characters. Technically, it does not need to be an array.

Consider this code:

```
char * p = malloc(20);
strcpy(p, "Hello, World!");
```

The pointer `p` will now point at a c-string that is not an array.

A char array does not need to be terminated with `\0`, but if it is, it is a c-string.

> **C standard 7.1.1.1**
>
> *A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.* The term multibyte string is sometimes used instead to emphasize special processing given to multibyte characters contained in the string or to avoid confusion with a wide string. A pointer to a string is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character. The length of a string is the number of bytes preceding the null character and the value of a string is the sequence of the values of the contained characters, in order.

So in short, arrays does not have a terminator at all. Not even character arrays. The closest thing is `sizeof` which will give you the space allocated for the array, but it will not work the same way as a null-terminator. If you have allocated space dynamically, or are using a pointer to access the array, you cannot even use `sizeof`. Well, you can, but you will not get the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that strings are null-terminated is for convenience. It's a convention adopted by a large number of stock procedures for string handling.

You *can* handle strings without null-termination, if you keep record of their lengths. In the same way you need to keep record of the length of your arrays, unless you want to terminate them with a sentinel value - but don't expect any ready-made functions to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

You have in C the possibility to declare a string in different ways (actual string type does not exists in C):

```
char MyStr[5] = "Jack"; 
char * MyStr  = "Jack"; 
char MyStr[5] = {'J','a', 'c', 'k', '\0'};
```

In case 1 and 2, when compiler encounters " " it will appends a null character '\0' at the end . 
In the last case you should append it manually (by convention you use '\0') but the main point is to not access elements outside the array.

Example :

```
while (*Mystr) /* Check against NULL char*/
{
  /* Do something */
}
```

If you use pointer to character type you cannot change it anymore after declaration because it will be stored in read only segment.