# How end of arrays other than character array is determined?

Tags: c, arrays, string

In C progrming language '\0' specify the end of the string in a character array , but when we are making integer arrays or float arrays or any other type of arrays null character (\0) is not included at the end ,then my question is how the end of integer ,float or any other type of arrays is known?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [End of array in C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579155/end-of-array-in-c-language)

Comment: You can use the first element of the array to define his size and then use the array as if we were on a base 1, i.e. `for (int i = 1; ...; i <= arr[0])`

Answer (score 1):

In some specific cases, some conventions are often used, such as `\0` for the end of a string, or `NULL` for the end of an array of pointers.  But often there is no such end-of-array marker, and instead you need to keep a count of the length.

For instance, if you have an array:

```
double a[10];
```

You may keep track of the length by using a marco to define it, or you may use `sizeof` to determine it:

```
(sizeof(a) / sizeof(double))
```

or:

```
(sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a))
```

Notice that the latter form does not require knowledge of the type of the elements of `a`.

People often write macros for these.  In these cases, you would  keep track of the length, and pass it along to any function that needs to operate on the array.